# What does "adjacent to water pipes within 3 feet of grade" mean?

Tags: plumbing, landscaping

Looking to see if I need to be careful using Termidor around water pipes and it says

> Treatment of soil adjacent to water pipes within 3 feet of grade should only be done by the backfill method.

What does it mean to be "3 feet of grade" mean?  Does that mean I shouldn't use it anywhere near my water main or sewer pipe?

How does one measure a unit "foot of grade"?  If the ground is flat, what distance is that?

Comment: Would think measure from top of soil/dirt down.  If pipes are three feet or less below surface, then be careful.

Comment: Sounds to me like *one* of the application methods involves jabbing probes or making holes in the soil, and they are afraid you might break the pipes? I wonder why they don't also caution about other buried utilities though (e.g. gas or electrical lines).

Comment: it says ... for example ... if you are leveling your yard, and the pipes are too close to surface, then you can add soil only ... you are not allowed to remove soil

Comment: I think it is meant that, when the pipe is within 3' to the ground surface, special care is required to backfill the trench. The justification is, the closer to the ground, the greater pressure will be passed onto the pipe and the surrounding soil from any movement on the ground. The pressure may cause the soil to settle excessively and damage the pipe, if it is not well compacted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pipes are not buried deeper than 3 feet/900cm, you should use "the backfill method" only, in their vicinity, whatever that method is (I'll let you read the manual to figure out what that is.)

Comment: Ahh... 3 feet of grade means 3 feet below grade... I was thinking it was something more complicated like some rise-over-run thing. Looking at it again it makes a lot more sense.  The term "of grade" instead of "below grade" threw me off.

Comment: For an admittedly contrived example, consider a pipe on a steep slope, that could be 3.5 feet "down" vertically but 2.5 feet from a point lower on the steep slope, at an angle. Pretty much it's "don't sue us if you break your pipes, we told you not to" and written by lawyers...